# Is "SNS" (Social Networking Site) used by native speakers of English?

Tags: initialisms

The acronym "SNS" (Social Networking Site) is made up of three English words, so it looks like it's English.

But is the acronym "SNS" (Social Networking Site) a "real" English acronym used in English by native speakers of English, or is it mainly used in English by native speakers of Japanese, and people from nearby Asian countries?

Comment: For all those who haven't heard SNS before, see here:[SNS is quite an established acronym.](http://www.gsmarena.com/glossary.php3?term=sns). In India, SNS has been used for Social Networking Site for quite a good time; though an average public might not know it, but SNS addicts are surely expected to know here. Of course, it might be an Asian thing.

Comment: There's a high chance of the acronym being mistaken for [SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service), or text messages.

Comment: @Mistu4u in Indian English, does "Asia" include India and other neighbouring countries?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, I can really not understand why it should not! By Asia, I mean all the countries that are within Asia. Also, so that you know, I said I am sure about usage of SNS in India and as you said Japanese also use it, so I thought it _might_ be an Asian thing. BDW just out of curiosity, I was under the impression that Japanese usually don't/can't speak English??!!

Comment: @Mistu4u different countries have different meanings for "Asia" or "Asian" - see [Does the term “Asian” have different meanings among various English-speaking countries?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34321/does-the-term-asian-have-different-meanings-among-various-english-speaking-cou/34334#34334)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, The answer there seemed incompetent. I have posted one of my own. you can [check it](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/128474/31053).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing only my own experience as a person living in Chicago and working in the online sector, I can say that this initialism is not in use at all in the US.

I *have* heard:

- “social” as an adjective attached to pretty much anything
- “social networking” as a general concept referring to all social sites collectively
- “social networks” ditto

In my experience, if one is referring to such sites, one names each in question.

*(We probably don't use as many, in general, so this might be more feasible for us.)*

Here's an example conversation:

> “What's Oggl?”
>
> “It's a **social** app for picture sharing.”
>
> “How does it work?”
>
> “It taps into your **social networks** and posts photos to one or more at a time.”
>
> “Oh? Which ones?”
>
> “**Facebook**, **Twitter**, and **Instagram**.”
>
> “I see. Sounds like a good use of **social networking**.”

---

Basically, as far as I can tell, the answer is that it does seem like a primarily Asian phenomenon. I have conversations similar to the one above every day, attend and give presentations on related topics, read my fair share of tech blogs, and I have never heard “SNS” spoken or seen it written.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a (British) English native speaker, involved in the technology sector, here. Haven't heard that acronym, and would be forced to look it up if I did.

Answer (score 4):

It's a valid, though uncommon, acronym.

I'd suggest that if you were to use it, that you provide its meaning upon first use. For example:

[We developed a Persuasive social network for physical Activity (PersonA) that combines automatic input of physical activity data, a smartphone, and a social networking system (SNS).](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23366348)

[For an overview of this space, including a definition of "social network sites," a history of SNSs, and a literature review](http://www.danah.org/researchBibs/sns.php)